# Remote desktop connection in C#

Tags: c#

I want to connect to a remote PC through my own app. I planned to make one in Visual Studio 2012.

I've searched around on the internet, and couldn't find the solution to make an remote connection inside of a form.

I've read something about the "Microsoft Terminal Services Control Type" Liberary (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET), but i couldn't get it working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: look up Windows Communication Foundation

Comment: What type of application are you trying to create in Visual Studio (WinForm, Console, Web, etc...)?  The type library in the codeproject link is a COM component, you probably need to create a WinForm project (like in the example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this guide : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET

It's a pretty outdated technology and only works on WinForms AFAIK. I tried using this control in one of my projects but decided to ditch it as I couldn't get it to resize dynamically.

Gaucomole is another good option. but is a bit more complex: http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/writing-you-own-guacamole-app.html

It runs in a browser and uses HTML5.

EDIT: Just noticed the article I linked is the one you were using. Why couldn't you get it working?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am not able to install the reference used on the guide properly (I think..) When I install the reference, i can't see this option: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RemoteDesktop_CSharpNET/remotedesktop3.jpg

Comment: @LuukIsbouts Yes, that took me a minute to figure out too. On the toolbox, right click a blank area (close all the tree views and right click on the empty space below everything), click Choose Items..., switch to the COM Components tab, and then choose Microsoft Terminal Services Control.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative for C#, you can also try [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille). It was first a commercial application that I made open source recently. Like Guacamole, it works from a web browser (HTML4 and HTML5) in pure javascript (no plugin).

But, as Jonathan said, if you want the remote connection into a winform, you'd better use the Microsoft Terminal Services COM control.